# Dividing sum of a column doesnt work properly with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to sum up columns in a CSV and divide a constant by the sum, but something doesn't seems to be right.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
NR==1{print}
NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( a[i] != 0 ) printf $wierdConst/a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}'
```

When I am not doing the division,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
NR==1{print}
NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( a[i] != 0 ) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}'
```

I get the total as 6440349377 and my constant `$wierdConst` is 39600000000. But when the division is done all I get is 0.0160752 which I don't know where it is getting from. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A shot in the dark - is `wierdConst` a shell variable? Awk is not shell - see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

Comment: You're dividing the constant by the sum, not dividing the sum by a constant.

Comment: EdMorton Thanks a lot.. I didnt know about this at all. Barmar's solution worked.. @Barmar Title is misleading. I wanted to divide constant by the sum of the column and your solution below worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables aren't expanded inside `awk` scripts. `$weirdconst` treats `weirdconst` as an `awk` variable, and `$` means to access that field number. Since you've never set `weirdconst`, this becomes `0`, so you're printing `$0/a[i]`.

Use the `-v` option to set an awk variable from the shell variable.

```
awk -v weirdconst=$weirdconst 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
NR==1{print}
NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( a[i] != 0 ) printf weirdConst/a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}'
```